# Spring Kafka Ssl Implemantation without using trust/keystores

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Hi I want to implement ssl feature in my spring kafka connection.To achive this I have to set SslTruststoreLocation,SslKeystoreLocations.But is it possible not to set classpath.Can I give the content o cert file as a string and running ssl implemantation like that?Is there any change to do that
Normal way we can set this properties

```
spring:
  kafka:
      ssl:
        key-password: pass
        keystore-location: /tmp/kafka.client.keystore.jks
        keystore-password: pass
        truststore-location: /tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
        truststore-password: pass
```

What I want to to set cert file content and running spring kafka implemantation

Comment: The java classpath is managed outside of the spring config. And certs aren't on the classpath, they are just on the hard drive. What do you mean it's not possible?

Comment: There's an open issue against the kafka-clients to support loading the stores from the class path: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685 - it has a lot of votes but not much activity. As a work around, you can copy the files from the class path to the file system (e.g. /tmp) before loading the `SpringApplication`. There is another work around mentioned in a comment on the JIRA.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I dont want to set keystore location.If it is possible I want to inject ssl cert file content and active ssl connection like that.

Comment: The Kafka client property needs set, regardless of if it's from spring properties or in the factories for the clients. There's no property that let's you pass in the certificates in a textual format. If that's your only option, then you'd need some process before starting your spring app that accepts that string, and writes the files for Kafka to use